# Flutter/Dart: Create/assign dynamic List

Tags: flutter, list, dart

A list "options" is generated from json file as below and no issue:
For simplicity, some parts were removed

```
Future getidea(String subject) async {

  List ideaList = [];
  for (var idea in ideaListTemp) {
    List options = [];
    options.add(idea["A"]);
    options.add(idea["B"]);
    options.add(idea["C"]);

    ideaList.add(ideaItem(
      idea["ideaText"],
      idea["ideaMedia"],
      idea[options],
    ));
  }
  return (ideaList);
}

class ideaItem {
  final String ideaText;
  final String ideaMedia;
  List? options;

  ideaItem(
    this.ideaText,
    this.ideaMedia,
    this.options,
  );
}
```

However, when I use "options" to create a Widget, this error occur.
error: The argument type 'List?' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'List'.

```
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Expanded(
      child: SingleChildScrollView(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(_horizontalMargin),
        physics: const AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics(),
        child: Column(
          children: [
            _buildOptions(widget.fromJSON.options), // this will have the error message
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
  
  Widget _buildOptions(List option) {
  List<Widget> listElevatedButton = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < option.length; i++) {
    //print(allOptions[i]);
    listElevatedButton.add(
      Builder(
        builder: (context) => Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
          child: ElevatedButton(
            onPressed: () {
              print('Use the update function');
            },
            child: Text(
              option[i],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
  return Column(children: listElevatedButton);
}
```

What is the best practice to solve the issue?

Answer (score 0):

The variable options is being used carelessly, You need to make sure that the `options` has value before using it, To do this you can put a null check like so:

`_buildOptions(widget.fromJSON.options)` -> `_buildOptions(widget.fromJSON.options ?? [])`

This will give an empty list to `_buildOptions` function as long as `options` is empty and It won't build any widgets in `_buildOptions` function.

I hope you understand the concept here.

Comment: Thanks. By changing to suggested code, it is now running.  However, still have issue.  From the json processing, the variable "options" have some items but for some reason, it is null when using in Widget.  Let me figure this out

Comment: Other values from widget.fromJSON can be extracted correctly.  Only widget.fromJSON.options is returning Null

Comment: It might be because of state management, You initialize `options` but you don't update UI to build from the new value of `options`, For this to solve I would recommend you use state management like GetX, Provider and for example, you call ```notifylisteners()`` to update UI, However ```setState``` also would work if you do it the correct way.

Answer (score 0):

Your properties 'options' has type (optional) ?List, which mean it can contain List or null value. And you try use 'options' like argument in '_buildOptions' function, which need type List, not (optional) ?List.

Rewrite code like this:

```
Column(
  children: [
    _buildOptions(widget.fromJSON.options ?? []),
  ],
),
```

If the "widget.fromJSON.options" value is null, the _buildOptions will have the empty List, otherwise, it will have the value of the "widget.fromJSON.options" value.

Good luck ;)